# Trouble finding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0 & 3 \\
  3 & -3 & -2\\
  2 & 0 & -2\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

I have trouble finding the correct eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda=-3$.

$[A - (-3)I]=\begin{bmatrix}
  5 & 0 & 3 \\
  3 & 0 & -2\\
  2 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & \frac{-2}{5} \\
  0 & 0 & \frac{-4}{5}\\
  0 & 0 & \frac{9}{5}\\
 \end{bmatrix}\sim
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

So I suppose the eigenvectors should be $[1, 0, 0]^T, [0, 0, 1]^T$. However, my computer says it is $[0, 1, 0]^T$. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot have two orthogonal proper eigenvectors for a single eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $1$, so your supposition is wrong.

The eigenspace of the eigenvalue $3$ is given by:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&3\\
3&0&-2\\
2&0&-5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and this gives the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
-x+3z=0\\
3x-2z=0\\
2x-5z=0
\end{cases}
$$
That have solutions for $x$ proportional to $z$ and $y$ free, so you can chose as aegenvector $[0,1,0]^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is correct, you just got the very last step wrong. Instead of taking the rows of the matrix, you have to solve the linear system:

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix}
v = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This yields
$$
v = [0,1,0]^T
$$
(or a scalar multiple)

Answer (score 1):

The eigenspace is the null space of the matrix $A-(-3)I$, so you want to find the solutions of the homogeneous linear system $(A-(-3)I)x=0$.

After reduction to echelon form, you can say that the system is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
x_1=0\\
x_3=0
\end{cases}
which in particular tells you that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an eigenvector and makes a basis for the eigenspace (which has dimension $1$, because the rank of $A-(-3)I$ is $2$).